# CASE WHEN NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set item quantity to 0 if it's `NULL` in `item_to_inv`

```
SELECT
  i.`id`,
  (
    SELECT
      SUM(
        CASE
          WHEN (
            `quantity` < 0
            OR `quantity` IS NULL
          ) THEN 0
          ELSE `quantity`
        END
      ) AS `quantity`
    FROM
      `item_to_inv`
    WHERE
      `item_id` = i.`id`
    GROUP BY
      `item_id`
  ) AS `quantity`
FROM
  `item` AS `i`
```

The following item ids: 5, 8 and 10 has not records in `item_to_inv`

What's wrong in following CASE WHEN statement?

```
CASE WHEN (`quantity` < 0 OR `quantity` IS NULL) THEN 0
```

[image]

Comment: Why not **`COALESCE(quantity, 0)`** ??

Comment: Have you tried seperating the two statements and run both of them individually? It might help to discover where the real problem is at.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the case statement, the problem is that for ids 5, 8 and 10 you are trying to sum no values which will return NULL (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)).

You can make the query return 0 for those ids by changing your query to:

```
SELECT i.`id`
, (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN (`quantity` < 0 OR `quantity` IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE `quantity` END), 0) AS `quantity` FROM `item_to_inv` WHERE `item_id` = i.`id` GROUP BY `item_id`) AS `quantity`
FROM `item` AS `i`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query

```
update Your_Table_name set quantity=0 where item_to_inv IS NULL ;
```

Comment: This is not what I want.. In "item_to_inv" are not records with NULL quantities

Comment: can you please describe it more clearly to understand?

Comment: @Kovi I'd just update my query. Now it will work fine as per expected

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your subquery is returning no record, so the 'when' clause isn't coming into play - there isn't a matching record.

Restructure your query to use an outer join to return a record even where there is no match

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e37faf/4

```
SELECT i.`id`, SUM(IFNULL(ii.`quantity`, 0))
FROM  `item` AS `i`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `item_to_inv` AS ii ON ii.`item_id` = i.`id`
GROUP BY i.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MySQL doesn't understand null as blank and that's why IS NULL doesn't work. Try changing your query to this

```
SELECT i.`id`, (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (`quantity` < 0 OR `quantity`='') THEN 0
ELSE `quantity` END) AS `quantity` FROM `item_to_inv` WHERE `item_id` = i.`id`
GROUP BY `item_id`) AS `quantity` FROM `item` AS `i`
```